# How does one count the number of columns in a table in Power BI using Dax

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

In Power BI desktop this is my 'Table1':

[image]

How do I count the columns (not rows) using DAX?  Ideally this would be a measure called ColCount.

The end results should be ColCount=4.  I have tried invoked functions, but new tables are unwanted.

Comment: Don't think you can do it in DAX, you can do it in PQ/M with the Table.ColumnCount function

Comment: What is that you need a count of columns for?   It seems like this ought to be known by the time you load your model, and then it can't change without a refresh so why would you need it in a measure.

Answer (score 0):

DAX doesn't really have a method for that.

PQ/M has this method:

```
let
    Source = Table.ColumnCount
in
    Source
```